# Prove that this metric space is compact.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $M = [0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Define a distance on $M$ given by $d:M\times M \to \mathbb{R}_{0}^{+} $ $$d(x,y) = \min\{|y-x|,1-|y-x|\}$$
>   It has already been shown that $(M,d)$ is a metric space. Prove that $(M,d)$ is compact.

I know that a set is compact if every open cover has a finite subcover $\iff$ sequentially compact $\iff$complete and totally bounded.

There is a hint for the problem, the hint is to show that $(1-\frac{1}{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$ with this distance. I have shown this but I fail to understand how this is relevant to the problem. I can't conclude completeness from this since this is not an arbitrary sequence?

I have also rewritten the distance as $$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      |y-x| & |y-x| \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
      1-|y-x| & |y-x| > \frac{1}{2}
   \end{cases}$$

Can someone explain the hint further to me or provide an alternative way to solve this question?

Comment: Picture $(M,d)$ as a circle of circumference 1, where the distance of two points is defined as the counterclockwise or clockwise distance along the circumference, whichever is shorter. It is intuitively obvious that this space is compact, so all that remains is to prove it.

Comment: I have next to no intuition for compactness, why is it obvious to you?

Comment: @pureundersgrad Because its (more or less) the metric of the circle inherited as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Explanation of the hint*. The idea is that if we have a sequence of points $s_1, s_2, \dots$ with none of the $s_i$'s equal to $1$, then one may find a convergent subsequence in the normal absolute metric on $[0, 1]$. Suppose we have this sequence of points $s_{i_1}, s_{i_2}, \dots$. Now suppose it is convergent to a value $s \neq 1$. By convergence, the (typical) distance between $s$ and $s_{i_j}$ will be (much) less than $1/2$ for $j \gg 0$. So this sequence converges in the strange metric to the same value $s$, *provided that* $s \neq 1$.

Now if the original subsequence converges to $1$, we may take a subsubsequence $s_{j_1}, s_{j_2}, \dots$ such that $s_{j_k} \geq 1 - 1/k$. Now show that this sequence converges to $0$, and therefore the space is sequentially compact.